# how to create unsigned char type array dynamically in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray, unsigned-char

I want to create an unsigned char array in objective c from the values of another nsmutablearray,
Please help me

```
unsigned char buffer2[24];
        buffer2[0] = 0X55; buffer2[1]=0x66; buffer2[2]=0x77; buffer2[3]=0x88; buffer2[4]=0x44;//print command
        buffer2[5] = 0X1D; buffer2[6]=0x6B; buffer2[7]=02; buffer2[8]=0x0D; 
        buffer2[9] = 0X35; buffer2[10]=0x30; buffer2[11]=0x30; buffer2[12]=0x30; buffer2[13]=0x33;
        buffer2[14] = 0X35; buffer2[15]=0x37; buffer2[16]=0x37; buffer2[17]=0x30; buffer2[18]=0x33;
        buffer2[19] = 0X30; buffer2[20]=0x31; buffer2[21]=0x38; buffer2[22]=0x37; buffer2[23]=0x30;
```

I want to pass values of this array dynamically.

Thanks in advance.
Shivam

Comment: If the answer provided by @Nekto is not what you want please make your question clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `malloc` or `calloc` functions of C:

```
int count = 24;
unsigned char *buffer = (unsigned char *)calloc(count, sizeof(unsigned char));
```

Don't forget to free it after using:

```
free(buffer);
```

Simple example:

```
NSMutableArray *array;
unsigned char *buffer = (unsigned char *)calloc([array count], sizeof(unsigned char));
for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++)
    buffer[i] = [[array objectAtIndex:i] unsignedCharValue];
// use array
free(buffer);
```